# M2 - Get all attributes from attribute group

Tags: magento2, attributes, magento2.3, product-view

I have an attribute set for example "Camera" in that set, we have multiple groups like; General, Recording, Storage, Monitoring etc...

All those groups have attributes which are specifications from that product, it can be a drop down, open field, multiple select.

What I have on the product detail page on the front-end is an accordion with the groups General, Recording, Storage, Monitoring. But I need to get all the attributes per group. Now I will load all the attributes piece by piece but there will be more than 60 attributes so that will be too much to handle.

Is there a way to load all the attributes from a specific group (not a Set).

Answer (score 2):

If you have the id of the group and assuming that `$product` is the current product you can get the attributes like this:

```
$product->getAttributes($groupId);
```

Comment: Thanks, do you also know how to find the groupId?